# Xamarin.Forms Binding with only dot as a path

Tags: xamarin.forms, binding, datacontext

As I know, in Xamarin.Forms you need a source and a path, in order
to perform a binding.

Now, I've encountered this piece of code:

```
<Grid Padding="10">
   <Label Text="{Binding Title}" d:Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="20"/>
</Grid>
```

- The source is initialized in the code by a Binding Context.
- The path in Text="{Binding Title}" is Title.
- What is the path in Text="{Binding .}  ?   (and yep, I know that d: means ignorable). I just don't remember I've seen dot character as a path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`{Binding .}` and `{Binding}` both refer to the entire `BindingContext`, instead of a specific property of the `BindingContext`

Comment: So in the example I wrote, how can it be the Text property (which is of type string) can get a value of...the entire object.

Comment: I assume the design time binding is just a string, so it binds a string to a string.   Or, that example is just wrong.  Or it just uses the `ToString()` method of the object

Comment: I'm going to check it and come back.

Comment: Yes, it binds it to the entire binding context, and the value of the expected string is the returned value of ToString() method of the object. Thank you!