# Gesture Recognisers using MVVM in .NET MAUI/Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui

I want to use Tap Gesture Recogniser with ICommand meaning using the ViewModel instead of the code behind.

I am making the gesture recogniser work through the code behind as shown below

**HomePage.xaml**

```
<CollectionView Margin="10,0,10,0"
                            ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                            ItemsLayout="VerticalList"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionPacks}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:QuestionPack">
                    <Frame Margin="5"
                           CornerRadius="10">
                        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                NumberOfTapsRequired="2"
                                Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped_1"/>
                        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <VerticalStackLayout Margin="5">
                        
                            <Label Text="{Binding Topic}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding TopicId}" />
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

Please note the `x:DataType=model:QuestionPack` in the DataTemplate.

**HomePage.xaml.cs**

```
private async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var selectedItem = ((VisualElement)sender).BindingContext as QuestionPack;

        if (selectedItem == null)
            return;


        LoadingQuestions.IsRunning = true;
        LoadingQuestions.IsEnabled = true;

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(QuestionsPage)}?topicSelected={selectedItem.TopicId}");

        LoadingQuestions.IsRunning = false;
        LoadingQuestions.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

This is working fine but I want to know how to implement this in my ViewModel. I came across 2 challenges while trying to do this.

1. I am supposed to use Command instead of Tapped under the TapGestureRecognizer. Whenever I bind the Command field to a Command in my code behind, the *x:DataType="model:QuestionPack"* raises a problem because the command is not defined in the model for the data template.
2. Even if applying the Command to the tap gesture recognizer wasn't causing building the app to fail, how am I to pass the object that is tapped into the code behind? In the code behind, I retrieve it using *object sender* but in the ViewModel, I don't know. I am guessing that that is where CommandParameters come into play but how to implement them is where I don't know.

And not to be a bother, if one can explain what `CommandParameter="{Binding .}"` means too.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's already an answer below about how to set the path binding, but to answer your other question `{Binding .}` means you want to bind to the entire object, not a specific property. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62816690/8395242

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create you ViewModel file and define as BindingContext
Example

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
      <vm:MyViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

Then define your Command and ICommand in your ViewModel( suposing that you know how to do )

And in your xaml file, you can do something like this

```
 <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
     <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" 
                           CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                           Command="{Binding 
                           Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:MyViewModel}}, Path=TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped}"/>                  
 </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
```

Tell me for more details

Comment: How do I get the item that was tapped?

Comment: @DarthScitus CommandParameter="{Binding .}", that's the item that was tapped

Comment: anyone care to translate this into pure c# for me?

Comment: @axa not sure why you'd want it but here you go: https://gist.github.com/MojoFilter/14e9547dc7d836ac209e39cb50f3fab7

Comment: @MojoFilter  just cuz i despise the xaml , use it as little as possible.  only found a few unsupported items so far that are worked around.

Comment: To each their own for sure, but that defined in xaml is way easier to read and maintain than the c# to me.